# CSV with ; separating to columns while there are multiple `"` at the end

Tags: c#, csv

I got a program which makes CSV files of some data. Those CSV files are separated with `;"` and for some reason they end with an `"`. Now those are some examples for those strings:

```
hello "; world "; 123 "
how "; are "; you "
```

Now those lines are easy to read, but now there are also lines like this:

```
just "; a "; li"ne" "
and "; another "; one"1" "
```

Because those lines do have `"`, my code will fail with the error: `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException: Line x cannot be parsed using the current Delimiters.`

My code looks like this now:

```
using (TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(csv_file_path, Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1250"))) //windows 1250 is the correct character encoding for European characters 
    {
        csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { ";" });
        csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
                            while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
        {
            string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();
            for (int i = 0; i < fieldData.Length; i++)
            {
                if (fieldData[i] == "")
                {
                    fieldData[i] = null;
                }
            }
            csvData.Rows.Add(fieldData);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why is `HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes` true? They aren't enclosed in quotes, just ending in quotes

Comment: In addtion to Sjors comment, your delimiter appears to be `";`, but you are calling `SetDelimiters` with just `;`. Have you tried using the correct delimiter?

Comment: @SjorsOttjes  youre right, my bad. I changed it now

Comment: @RB. I tried this: `csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "\";" });` and got `system.argumentexception: input array is no longer than the number of columns in this table`

Comment: This format is messed up even for a CSV file... can't you do anything in order to get somewhat proper formatted CSV (one delimiter character, potentially using `"` as field enclosing character)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have the wrong delimiter set as I put in my comment:

### Linqpad

```
using (TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(@"C:\temp\temp.csv", Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252")))
{
    csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "\";" });
    csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = false;
    while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
    {
        string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();
        for (int i = 0; i < fieldData.Length; i++)
        {
            if (fieldData[i] == "")
            {
                fieldData[i] = null;
            }
        }
        fieldData.Dump();
    }
}
```

### Input data

```
hello "; world "; 123 "
how "; are "; you "
just "; a "; li"ne" "
and "; another " one"1" "
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Hey, I also made an error in my last line, it should be: another "; one. It fixed my problem tho, now I only got some `"`'s at my seperated parts. At the first, third and fifth part I got an `"` at the end and beginning

Comment: @wouterdejong It should only be your final part that has a trailing `"`, and that is because your input data has a trailing `"`. I would suggest just removing all trailing `"` characters from the file before it is read in...

Comment: And somehow it only works this way `csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { ";" });` and not with `{"\";"}`

Comment: It works fine for me (as per the code I attached). The only changes I made were setting the delimiter correctly, setting the encoding to 1252 (as that's correct for my machine) and setting HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes to false. Have you run my code to see the output?

Comment: I did set the HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes to false, and this seemed to work.

Comment: Cool - so you've made both changes (delimiter and quotes) and everything is working correctly now?

Comment: Well not really yet because I still got data with `"`'s. It looks like my odd columns got `"`'s on the outside, but the equal columns doenst got `"`'s on the outside